# Asp.net core MVC post parameter always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, .net-core

I am new to MVC core.

I have created a project with MVC core which has a controller. This controller has Get and Post action methods. If i pass data to Get method using query string it works fine, but when i pass complex JSON to post method, then it always shows me null.

Here what i am doing:

**Post Request**

```
URL: http://localhost:1001/api/users
Content-Type: application/json
Body: 
{
   "Name":"UserName",
   "Gender":"Gender of the user",
   "PhoneNumber":"PhoneNumber of the user"
}
```

**Here is the Post action method**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/users")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]User newUser)
{
   ...
}
```

When post request is called, then **newUser** always shows me null. And if i remove **[FromBody]** attribute then i receive newUser object but all of its fields are null.

Please help me and guide me in this issue.

**EDITED**

Here is my **User** class

```
public class User{

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Gender { get; set; }
   public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I had done same as described [here](https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/web-api-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc-6-asp-net-5/) for json data, but still receives null.

Comment: DO you have any middleware that might intercept the request? have you done a wireshark or fiddler trace?

Comment: No, I am sending request using postman. I don't know how to trace the request using fiddler.

Comment: Download fiddler, and watch the requests and inspect them, make sure what you're sending matches up on the actual request. It's really not complicated to use

Comment: Thanks i will try it, but meanwhile let me know if i am doing anything wrong in above code.

Comment: What is name of your controller??

Comment: @RaviPatel how you are sending data using PostMan ???

Comment: Remove `[FromBody]` this extracts simple types from body. That explains why it works when you removed it. Check to make sure that the properties of your JSON match the `User` object so the that ModelBinder will populate the matching properties on the model. Show your definition of the `User` class

Comment: @Nkosi I tried that too, and i am sure all the properties of JSON matches with the User object. Even though i get all properties as null

Comment: @RaviPatel, show the `User` class definition.

Comment: @RaviPatel - are errors captured in the ModelState ?

Comment: @Nikosi Please see User class in Edited section

Comment: While it may just be a typo, shouldn't your Content Type be `application/json` instead of `applicaton/json`?

Comment: Seems odd to post `"Id": null` when Id is an int (not nullable).

Comment: @blins I tried it sending **Id: 0** and also tried json with no **Id** property as well. Still it did not work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This could be because of how the null values are being handled. Set NullValueHandling to Ignore in AddJsonOptions and see if that works.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions=>
        {
            jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, It worked just fine. Now i know why the data received was null.

Comment: THANK you .. I don't think I would have figured this out soon without your help.

Answer (score 11):

Note the original method `Post([FromBody] User newUser)`

For future readers from google, this same issue could arise if the method was `Post(User newUser)`

Note the **lack** of `[FromBody]`. This is a departure from previous versions of MVC where these parameters were *generally* inferred.

If you're an existing **MVC5** developer who finds this page regarding **AspNetCore.MVC**, make sure to double check that you have `[FromBody]` decorated where relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I created new ASP.NET Core project, added your functionality, and it works. Please, checkout [this project](https://github.com/rZinnatov/aspnet-core-test) on github.

Also, see screenshot of log with simple communication with this controller from browser console: [Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvNkv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0`?

If you are, try sending this object as your body in a request (camel cased properties):

```
{
   "name":"UserName",
   "gender":"Gender of the user",
   "phoneNumber":"PhoneNumber of the user"
}
```

Comment: Yes i am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 Also i am sending data in the request body

Comment: Yes, but, use camel cased property names in the JSON.

Comment: It is the default in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0`.