# Asp.net Core Post parameter is always null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm sending POST from fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost:55924/api/Product HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:55924
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 84

{"Ean″:”1122u88991″,”Name″:”Post test″,"Description":"Post test desc"}
```

But Post method always gets null.

```
// POST api/Product
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostProduct([FromBody]Product product)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _repo.Add(product);

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetToode",product);
}
```

When I use [FormBody] product is always null, when not using it product is valued but with all fields being null. Product class is simple.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string EAN { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
}
```

i tried adding NullValueHandling to ConfigureServices as proposed in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455954/asp-net-core-mvc-post-parameter-always-null) but no use.

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
    {
        jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

Comment: try it sending all properties. Include `ProductID` and `CategoryID`.

Comment: This is like you mapping field is not matching, name should be same as in product class, also try with removing `[FromBody]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had to correct the double quotes in your POST request and it worked. Try this:

```
{"Ean":"1122u88991","Name":"Post test","Description":"Post test desc"}
```

See screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Honestly I feel so so dumb right now, that I didn't noticed it myself.

Comment: It is not clear what quotes this answer refers to because the question was since edited a few times. FYI, OP used a mix of `″ ”` and `"` characters in the original request body.

Answer (score 6):

I experience a similar problem but I had no check for the validity of the `ModelState` as the OP. When this happens, inspecting it in debug mode will likely point you to what's wrong with the model:

[image: QuickWatch window]

In this example I was using an invalid string `'A'` as test value for a `Guid` property, so the model was always null.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I was shooting in the dark before stumbling upon this

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. It turned out that I had no public parameterless constructor for class of incoming instance. In this case, `Product` had only protected constructors and parameter was always null no matter what. Hope it helps somebody.