# ASP.NET Core API POST parameter is always null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have read the following:

- [Asp.net Core Post parameter is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748153/asp-net-core-post-parameter-is-always-null)
- [asp.net webapi 2 post parameter is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927031/asp-net-webapi-2-post-parameter-is-always-null)
- [web-api POST body object always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741943/web-api-post-body-object-always-null)
- [Web Api Parameter always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624306/web-api-parameter-always-null)

**My endpoint:**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/getter/validatecookie")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetRankings([FromBody] string cookie)
{
    int world = 5;
    ApiGetter getter = new ApiGetter(_config, cookie);
    if (!await IsValidCookie(getter, world))
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid CotG Session");
    }
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("cotgCookie", cookie);
    return Ok();
}
```

**My request:**

```
$http.post(ENDPOINTS["Validate Cookie"],  cookie , {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
```

Where `cookie` is the a string I am sending from the user input.

The request posts to the endpoint with the appropriate data. However, my string is always null. I have tried removing the `[FromBody]` tag, as well as adding a `=` in front of the posted data with no luck. I have also tried adding and removing different content types with all combinations of the above.

The reason why I am doing this specific action is long and does not matter for this question.

Why is my parameter always null no matter what I seem to do?

Edit: I have also tried using `{cookie: cookie}`

**Edit2**: The request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:54093/getter/validatecookie
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:[::1]:54093
```

**Response Headers**

```
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 23 Jan 2017 03:12:54 GMT
Server:Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcRG91Z2xhc2cxNGJcRG9jdW1lbnRzXFByb2dyYW1taW5nXENvdEdcQ290RyBBcHBcc3JjXENvdEdcZ2V0dGVyXHZhbGlkYXRlY29va2ll?=
```

**Request Headers**

```
POST /getter/validatecookie HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:54093
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 221
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:54093
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:54093/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

**Request Payload**

```
=sec_session_id=[redacted]; _ga=[redacted]; AWSELB=[redacted]
```

Comment: Have you used something like Fiddler or the browser's network console, to make sure that the POST is sending the body properly?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Yes, I mentioned that it does post with the appropriate data. The data is sent in the request.

Comment: Instead of posting how you are making the AJAX request, could you post the actual HTTP request with its headers and its body. That might help the trouble shooting.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I have added the request in there

Comment: Your request payload is not JSON whereas your Content-Type is application/json.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Yes, that is the current example, one of several dozen. I have mentioned that I have added and removed various content types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133773/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-douglas-gaskell).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem is that the `Content-Type` is `application/json`, whereas the request payload is actually `text/plain`. That will cause a 415 Unsupported Media Type HTTP error.

You have at least two options to align then `Content-Type` and the actual content.

#### Use application/json

Keep the `Content-Type` as `application/json` and make sure the request payload is valid JSON. For instance, make your request payload this:

```
{
    "cookie": "=sec_session_id=[redacted]; _ga=[redacted]; AWSELB=[redacted]"
}
```

Then the action signature needs to accept an object with the same shape as the JSON object.

```
public class CookieWrapper
{
    public string Cookie { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of the `CookieWrapper` class, or you can accept dynamic, or a `Dictionary<string, string>` and access it like `cookie["cookie"]` in the endpoint

```
public IActionResult GetRankings([FromBody] CookieWrapper cookie)

public IActionResult GetRankings([FromBody] dynamic cookie)

public IActionResult GetRankings([FromBody] Dictionary<string, string> cookie)
```

#### Use text/plain

The other alternative is to change your `Content-Type` to `text/plain` and to add a plain text input formatter to your project. To do that, create the following class.

```
public class TextPlainInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
{
    public TextPlainInputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add("text/plain");
        SupportedEncodings.Add(UTF8EncodingWithoutBOM);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(UTF16EncodingLittleEndian);
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string);
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(
        InputFormatterContext context, 
        Encoding encoding)
    {
        string data = null;
        using (var streamReader = context.ReaderFactory(
            context.HttpContext.Request.Body, 
            encoding))
        {
            data = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

        return InputFormatterResult.Success(data);
    }
}
```

And configure Mvc to use it.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.InputFormatters.Add(new TextPlainInputFormatter());
});
```

#### See also

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5137

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just tried, same deal. Do the ASP.NET parameters not accept data in the standard way other frameworks do?

Comment: Got it... ASP.NET Core does not support `text/plain` as a `Content-Type` out of the box.

Comment: Shaun, I ended up using `Dictionary<string,string>` with a `{"cookie":cookie}` object. I then access it like `cookie["cookie"]` in my endpoint. I will accept your answer if you can add that as one of the potential solutions.

Comment: This should not be the answer. You can send a string really easily in .Net Core without all this jiggery pokery. Refer my answer below

Comment: A plain text formatter is included with ASP.NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-formatters#when-to-use-custom-formatters

Comment: You can see he is deriving from the `TextInputFormatter` in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters`. However that is an abstract class and the only derived classes at this time are for JSON and XML.  That said, I really wish `TextPlainInputFormatter` was included.  Thanks so much, Shaun!

Comment: This thing should be included in the framework. MVC should also have that formatter added by default.

Answer (score 11):

Shaun Luttin's answer works, but it misses one important piece of information. The reason your string is not recognised is because it is not a ***JSON*** string.

Do this;

```
var payload=JSON.stringify("=sec_session_id=[redacted]; _ga=[redacted]; AWSELB=[redacted]");
```

Then you can leave the controller as it is;

```
$.ajax({
    url: http://localhost:54093/getter/validatecookie,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: payload
});
```

It is embarassing how long this took me to figure out. I really hope it helps someone!

Comment: Worked. Using axios to post payload

Answer (score 9):

ridiculously,
in dot net core you cannot use just "frombody string parameter".
you should make a model class for just one string parameter.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetRankings([FromBody] string cookie)
```

=>

```
//1. make a model. MyCookie.cs
class MyCookie{
   public string Cookie { get; set; }
}
//2. edit your parameter
public async Task<IActionResult> GetRankings([FromBody] MyCookie cookie)
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, just adding `[FromBody]` to the parameters list solved the problem.

May this save someone's time.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this for far to long and finally, after looking at what a DevExpress control was doing for "PUT"ting to a Razor Page, I discovered this nugget:

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/GoalGrid?handler=Single",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        data: {values: single }
    })
```

GoalGrid.cshtml.cs

```
public JsonResult OnPutSingle(string values)
{ 
     // Do stuff with 'values' here 
}
```

The trick is to use the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" as your contentType for the request.  This way you don't need to create a class for a single string value.  And things work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to put the body in quotes such that it represents a `string`. You also need to leave the request type as `application/json`. That way the media type formatter will figure it out:

```
"=sec_session_id=[redacted]; _ga=[redacted]; AWSELB=[redacted]"
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: The variable `cookie` is already a string, it is getting passed around the JS as a string.

Comment: Right, but the request payload also needs to be encapsulated in double quote characters in order for the media type formatter to handle the `[FromBody]` attribute correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to post string data by .Net Desktop Client to .NET Core host. I was getting unsupported media error. I have followed Shaun Luttin's answer and worked fine. The I found something easier to get just string data as folows in case someone else finds useful:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Request/Echo")]
public async Task<string> Echo()
{
    using (var Reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        return await Reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

[This post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Sep/14/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-in-ASPNET-Core-API-Controllers) is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had it setup like @guhyeon suggested, with a model class containing only a string property. Except, it wasn't defined as a property, it was simply

```
public class PdfInfoRequestDto
{
    public string PdfInBase64;
}
```

And for some reason, this worked for a .net framework 4.7.2 webapi and I could receive the value I needed from the request body. But when I tried replicating the same in a .net core 3.1 webapi, with the same request, models and everything, the value in PdfInBase64 always arrived in my controller as *null*. After changing the field to a property:

```
public string PdfInBase64 { get; set; }
```

I started correctly getting the value that was being passed in the request body.

Answer (score 0):

My particular issue was that the model binding was silently failing for a JSON model. (It was always null).

As I had the exact JSON being posted, I was able to debug it locally by running the web-service locally, and posting to my controller via cURL (can use POSTMAN).

Using the below code, I was able to see the exact exception occurring during serialization.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult MyAction([FromBody] dynamic request)
    {            
        if (request != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var objAttempt =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(
                        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [FromForm] on both parameters fixed it for me.  As in :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Insrtmyinfo([FromForm] string firstparam, [FromForm] string secndparam)
```

...