# ASP.NET Core API POST parameter send in JSON.stringify is always null (i don't want to make or bind model for parameter)

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

This question seems copy of [ASP.NET Core API POST parameter is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798814/asp-net-core-api-post-parameter-is-always-null) this link , but i have tried all the options given for this question.

> Mine axios call.

```
let finalData = JSON.stringify(data);
axios.post("url",{ headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }},{data:finalData});

finalData after JSON.stringyfy =
{"test1":{"name":"abc","id":1},"test2":{"name":"xyz","id":1}}
```

> Core controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult doSomething(string data)
{
 ...mine logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use Model binding which help accept the values on server side easily . But if you want to get raw data and then deserialize it manually , one way is to do some custom processing of the Request.Body :

JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      var data = {
          test1: {
              name: 'abc',
              id: 1
          },
          test2: {
              name: 'xyz',
              id: 1
          }
      }

      axios.post("/Home/Test", data  );
  })
</script>
```

Sever side :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var result  =  await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    .....
}
```

But i would always suggest use Model Binding instead .

Answer (score 0):

there's an error in the format you requested.

You can try this.

```
   return axios.get(url, {
          params: data,
          headers: {'yl-authorization': this.token}//设置header信息
        }).then((res) => {
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Formdata object:

```
let finalData = JSON.stringify(data);
var formData = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'data',  finalData);

$.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    //TODO: use reponse from API
  }
});
```

Hope you'll find this helpful.