# ASP.NET Core 5 API POST parameter is always null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I think i might be too dumb, but I've already ready this answers:

[ASP.NET Core API POST parameter is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798814/asp-net-core-api-post-parameter-is-always-null)
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2202

But none of above worked for me.

This is my model:

```
[DataContract]
    public class Video
    {
        public Video()
        {

        }

        public Video(string titulo, string descricao, string url)
        {
            this.Titulo = titulo;
            this.Descricao = descricao;
            this.Url = url;
        }

        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string Titulo { get; private set; }
        public string Descricao { get; private set; }
        public string Url { get; private set; }

    }
```

This is my controller:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class VideosController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IVideoRepository _videoReposiroty;

        private readonly ILogger<VideosController> _logger;

        public VideosController(ILogger<VideosController> logger,
            IVideoRepository videoReposiroty)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _videoReposiroty = videoReposiroty;
        }

        // GET: Videos
        public IEnumerable<Video> Get()
        {

            return _videoReposiroty.GetVideos();
        }

        // GET: Videos/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            var video = _videoReposiroty.GetVideo(id);
            if (video == null)
            {
                return "{message: \"Não encontrado\"}";
            }
            var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(video);
            return jsonString;
        }

        // POST: Videos
        [HttpPost]
        public Video Post(Video video)
        {
            return _videoReposiroty.CreateVideo(video);
        }
    }
```

And this is my request:

[image]

But all the never que the right body.
I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: `private set;` Remove `private`. Also read https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/ .

Comment: I fell really really dumb right now. Hahaha
But this solved!
Thank you!!!

Comment: All good. Have a great day.