# ASP.Net Core 3.1 - Post parameter is always NULL in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a basic API service in ASP.Net Core 3.1.

Before going to the problem description, I have already gone through these questions-

- [Post parameter is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984040/post-parameter-is-always-null?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)
- [Asp.net Core Post parameter is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748153/asp-net-core-post-parameter-is-always-null)
- [ASP.NET Core API POST parameter is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798814/asp-net-core-api-post-parameter-is-always-null)
- [Web Api Parameter always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624306/web-api-parameter-always-null)
- [web-api POST body object always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741943/web-api-post-body-object-always-null)

but, none of fixing my issue.

What I am trying to do is create a basic API which will take a `string` from the API then use the `string` and give a response based on the string. What I am doing is like this in `Controller`-

```
[Route("/")]
[ApiController]
[EnableCors]
public class XmlValidatorController : ControllerBase
{
    ........................
    ........................

[HttpPost("verify_string")]
public ActionResult<ICollection<Certificate>> VerifyXmlString([FromQuery(Name = "xml")] string xml)
//string xml                                => Giving Null
//[FromQuery(Name = "xml")] string xml      => Giving Null
//[FromBody] string xml                     => Unsupported Media Type - 415
//[FromBody] dynamic xml                    => Unsupported Media Type - 415
//HttpRequestMessage msg                    => Unsupported Media Type - 415
{
    ...............
    ...............
}
```

If I am creating a `POST` request from [`POST Man`](https://www.postman.com/), I am creating like this-

[image: Header Postman]

and

[image: body postman]

In my controller, if I am putting a debugging pointer, I am getting this-

[image: Controller]

So, I am always getting `null` in `POST` request.

If I use others in the function parameter, I am getting this errors-

- string xml                                => Giving Null
- [FromQuery(Name = "xml")] string xml      => Giving Null
- [FromQuery(Name = "xml")] string xml      => Giving Null
- [FromBody] string xml                     => Unsupported Media Type - 415
- [FromBody] dynamic xml                    => Unsupported Media Type - 415
- HttpRequestMessage msg                    => Unsupported Media Type - 415

Can anyone please help me find the parameter string from the Controller action paramenter/ function parameter (XML).

### Re-

I haven't tried with creating a model for the request because I think it will make the code a little more complex and that become overkill as I need just a string.

### Re-re-

My `Startup.cs` file has no special configuration, it is default code provided during code creation. The code for the file can be found in [here](https://github.com/AbrarJahin/BCC-CA-XMLSignVerifierService/blob/master/Startup.cs). And code for controller can be found in [here](https://github.com/AbrarJahin/BCC-CA-XMLSignVerifierService/blob/master/Controllers/XmlValidatorController.cs).

Complete Codebase can be found in ***[this Github Repo](https://github.com/AbrarJahin/BCC-CA-XMLSignVerifierService)***.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Why are you doing FromQuery vs sending in FromBody?

Comment: Also trying sending as Raw in postman, that’s a permutation you haven’t listed

Comment: Try sending as Json payload and get that to succeed.

Comment: Yes, FromBody expects json payload, not form encoded, as @jbooker mentions.

Comment: So, do I need to change request in postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `FromQuery` attribute for your parameter. In fact when you post `x-www-form-urlencoded` form there's a certain content-type specified that tells model binding system all query parameters are actually form fields. So you have to either define `FromForm` attribute for `xml` parameter,

```
[HttpPost("verify_string")]
public ActionResult<ICollection<Certificate>> VerifyXmlString([FromForm] string xml)
```

either pass it as a query parameter using Params tab in postman.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to populate [FromQuery] params, You have to provide it from URL and in your case, it could be like:

[POST] https://localhost:44377/verify_string?xml=asd

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying `Content-Type: application/json` in Postman, but your payload is not JSON. Hence the "Unsupported Media Type" error.

Change the `Content-Type` to `text/xml` or `application/xml` and try again.

Comment: Please read the question carefully my friend. I have tried with your solution and Unsupported Media Type - 415

Comment: Where in your question does it say you've changed the content-type?