# MVC Core Action not binding from angularjs POST

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having a problem by where I am posting an object to an MVC Core controller from a simple angularjs page.

The object at my MVC action is not binding although the object itself isn't null which is the usual problem with this.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

This is my angular service code:

```
this.getQuote = function (priceRequest) {
    return $http.post('/quote/getcost', { priceRequest });
};
```

which is called by:

```
quoteService.getQuote(this.quoteData).then(function (cost) {
    $scope.quoteData.quoteCost = cost.data;
});
```

where this.quoteData is:

```
$scope.quoteData = {
                detailLevel: '0',
                fileLengthHours: 0,
                fileLengthMinutes: 1,
                excessiveSpeakersCount: 1,
                industry: null,
                deliveryTime: '1',
                additionalInformation: '',
                quoteCost: null
            };
```

This is the payload
[image]

and this is the POST:
[image]

Finally my C# MVC Core action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetCost([FromBody]PriceRequest priceRequest)
{
    var price = _priceCalculator.GetPrice(priceRequest);

    return new JsonResult(price);
}
```

Although the object posted in is not null, none of the values have been bound:
[image]

This is the PriceRequest object:

```
public class PriceRequest
{
    public JobDetailLevel DetailLevel { get; set; }

    public int FileLengthHours { get; set; }

    public int FileLengthMinutes { get; set; }

    public int? ExcessiveSpeakersCount { get; set; }

    public JobIndustry Industry { get; set; }

    public JobDeliveryTime DeliveryTime { get; set; }

    public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }        
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How is your .Net PriceRequest object defined?

Comment: Just added to the question Brad. Anything that isn't a string or int is an enum

Comment: Your screen shot of the "POST" is missing the body. What does the body look like?

Comment: The payload screenshot above it has it in?

Comment: `priceRequest{DetailLevel: "0"...` looks wrong, I'd expect something more like `priceRequest{DetailLevel:{...etc}}` basically your json doesn't seem correct

Comment: Do you have `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` added in your `Startup.cs`? If not, you will either need to add it or change names of your models and their properties to pascal case.

Comment: eminlala I have added with no joy still:services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so courtesy of this post:
[Asp.net core MVC post parameter always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455954/asp-net-core-mvc-post-parameter-always-null)

I needed to add this to my startup.cs:

```
.AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
{
  jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Thanks to those who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the *{ }* from around the priceRequest variable on the angular side.

Like:

```
return $http.post('/quote/getcost', priceRequest);
```

Comment: My object at the server side becomes null doing this

Comment: It can't "become null".  You're passing in a json object as a parameter to this function:

this.getQuote = function (priceRequest) {
}

By wrapping priceRequest with { } you're wrapping your json object in another object so it isn't binding the body on the server side